# Param causes "does not map to Unicode" error in Catalyst

Tags: perl, unicode, catalyst

The following will demonstrate the error:

```
catalyst.pl Hello
cd Hello
echo "encoding utf8" >> hello.conf
script/hello_server.pl -r
```

Then navigate to `http://localhost:3000/?q=P%E9rl` in your browser and you'll get a `400 Bad Request`.

It appears to be Catalyst's `_handle_param_unicode_decoding()` method which is generating this error.  Given that this error is trivial to generate, it's showing up in the error logs and Google has failed me in trying to fix this error. I can't stop users from entering query strings like that. How can I work around this?

Comment: In UTF-8, the %-encoded data %E9 is indeed invalid (does not constitute valid character data or start thereof), so what do you think that *should* happen?

Answer (score 3):

URLs are suppose to be encoded using UTF-8. RFC3986:

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set, the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8 character encoding; then only those octets that do not correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-encoded.

`P E9 r l` is not valid UTF-8.

I believe you were going for `Pérl` (é is U+00E9)? That would be

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -MURI::Escape -E'say uri_escape_utf8("Pérl")'
P%C3%A9rl
```

`400 Bad Request` is an appropriate error for providing a bad URL. If the user doesn't want to see this error, they should use a valid URL. You could override Catalyst's default error handling behaviour (e.g. to provide a more precise error page) using [`handle_unicode_encoding_exception()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst.pm#handle_unicode_encoding_exception-exception_context).

Comment: I keep forgetting that code points 128 to 255 are multi-byte.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I realize that this is still bad. Many of the URLs for this app (and another one I'm working on) are for GET requests which take no parameters, so I'd very much like to *not* kill the app because of bad data that I'm not going to use anyway.

Comment: Really? Sounds like you're talking about a web-based API. I think it would be better to catch the bad client sooner rather than later.

Comment: No, plenty of Catalyst apps with have this issue. Why should a GET request using malformed data that isn't being used be a fatal error? I've tried this on a number of Web sites and it's hard to find any of them suffering a fatal error because of this. When you have a Web site with millions of visitors, it's impossible to stop this from happening from time to time.

Comment: Because the same app will pass bad data for parameters that *are* used too, so there's no reason to do extra work to allow unused bad data. Like I said, it's better to catch bad clients sooner rather than later

Comment: @Ovid: so what you want is some kind of proceed-with-no-params if params are invalid option?

Comment: ysth: I'd prefer to have an option to not kill my application if data I don't use is bad. Otherwise, proceed-with-no-params might be an OK recourse.

Can you imagine a popular web site directing traffic to your home page, but they've included a `utm_source` query parameter with a bad encoding and now all of your new visitors see a `Bad Request` page? That's not good and makes no sense.

Comment: You can change `$Catalyst::Plugin::Unicode::Encoding::CHECK`

Comment: I am no sure about back when this answer was written, but nowadays there also is [handle_unicode_encoding_exception()](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst.pm#handle_unicode_encoding_exception-exception_context) which you can override so that it doesn't die on errors.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a method in Catalyst.pm that you can modify in your subclass (Hello.pm in the example above) which controls how errors look.  If you want to surprise those types of errors you can do so.  Take a look at:

https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90077/lib/Catalyst.pm#L3108

you can override that method if you like.

Alternatively if you have a proposal for a code change or some sort of configuration option you can branch off the Catalyst github repo and send me a pull request with your ideas:

https://github.com/perl-catalyst/catalyst-runtime

These methods are currently considered somewhat private but I am considering making them fully public.